How to change `podman machine init --image` to Ubuntu or other distribution?
I have Windows 10 WSL2, I install podman.
After installing - podman machine init, Fedora is always installed as default OS in podman
Because, in my opinion, the most stable option for starting the Linux subsystem with podman-compose support - there is only one question left.
How to start a machine with an arbitrary distribution?
We tried to run it like this podman machine init --image docker://docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest But this did not give any results.
Who can tell me?

I don't have a copy of Windows handy to check the command, but what you are doing should work according to the docs (https://docs.podman.io/en/stable/markdown/podman-machine.1.html) - it doesn't show up in the list of machines I assume? If you switch linux distros you won't have the latest version of podman available though - Debian-based distros lag Red-Hat based ones (podman is a Red-Hat project, so they do all there work on Fedora)

Thanks for the explanations
